# Windows Forms Datagridview (Select part of text in cell with mousepointer but dont allow edit) VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, windows-forms-designer

Hey guys i have a gridview on my form with readonly = false and enabled = true so i can select a part of the text in a cell of a datagridview. This works ok but when i have the settings like this its also possible to edit the text and thats the part i dont whant.

So i am looking for a solution to be able to select a part of the text within a cell of a datagridview but dont allow the users to edit the values that are in there.

Tanx in Advantage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
dataGridView1.ReadOnly = false and dataGridView1.enabled = true

Private Sub dataGridView1_EditingControlShowing(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs)
 If TypeOf e.Control Is TextBox Then
' Set the TextBoxCell to readonly
Dim textBoxCell As TextBox = DirectCast(e.Control, TextBox)
textBoxCell.[ReadOnly] = True
 End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I tryd that also but than i cant select a part of text with mouse pointer