# How to highlight text in gridview for copy but set text not changeable in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, gridview, editmode

I have a gridview which is filled by a query. I want to allow the user to highlight and copy text from the  cell, which is double clicked.
here is my event code:

```
Private Sub datagridview2_CellDoubleClick(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles datagridview2.CellDoubleClick
    datagridview2.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.CellSelect

    datagridview2.CurrentCell.Selected = True
    datagridview2.ReadOnly = False
    datagridview2.BeginEdit(False)


End Sub
```

This works fine with the exception that the user is allowed to change text.
I just want to let him highlight the text and copy and paste it. I guess it is an easy edit control but i dont know it yet. Can somebody help out?

Edit: I removed the word paste because it sound confusing. 
Here is an example: 
cell value: "5 dublettes found: 11111, 22222,33333,44444,5555" 
I want to make it possible to only highlight 33333 and copy it via strg+c. With the  premise, that the cell value is not changable.

Friendly greetings

b101

Comment: if you allow them to paste text it is changing text.  your question contradictory

Comment: well yes, my text is contradictory to understand. I mean copy it from the grid and then paste it into excel..

Comment: one alternative option might be to dd a context menu to the cell with a menu item to copy the text

Comment: Your suggestion sounds good  but I still have the problem that not a spicific part of the cell can be copied. And in my Programm its possible to select a single cell, which can be copied with strg + c

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer to my question here:

[Windows Forms Datagridview (Select part of text in cell with mousepointer but dont allow edit) VB.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12971057/windows-forms-datagridview-select-part-of-text-in-cell-with-mousepointer-but-do)

it works perfektly!